# Separable filter on numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy, gil

Say I have a numpy array `a`, and I want to create a new array, `b` such that
`b[i, j]` is a function of, say:

```
a[i-1, j-1], a[i-1, j  ], a[i-1, j+1],
a[i  , j-1], a[i  , j  ], a[i  , j+1],
a[i+1, j-1], a[i+1, j  ], a[i+1, j+1]
```

What would be the fastest way to do this?

As this is a separable filter, is there any way to run this in multiple threads? (not processes, because I would have to copy the data back)

Or is writing C code to bypass the GIL mandatory?

Partial solutions (like assuming the function is linear) are welcome too.

Comment: Do you mean like a rolling/moving window or filter?  the example in this link is for a summation for a 3x3 window over a 2D array   http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268

Comment: Sounds like a number of other SO questions, most using the term `sliding windows` (or moving).  Though most focus on iterating over the window, not on splitting up the task among threads or processes.

Answer (score 1):

An idealized `numpy` way of working with a sliding window like this is to construct a 4D array

```
C.shape = (N,M,3,3)
```

where

```
C[i,j,:,:] = np.array([a[i-1, j-1], a[i-1, j  ], a[i-1, j+1],
                       a[i  , j-1], a[i  , j  ], a[i  , j+1],
                       a[i+1, j-1], a[i+1, j  ], a[i+1, j+1]])
```

and write your function do some sort of reduction on the last 2 dimensions.   `sum` or `mean` would be typical, e.g.

```
B = C.sum(axis=(2,3))
```

Other SO questions show how to use `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to construct such an array.  But with only a 3x3 subarray, it might be just as fast to do something like

```
C = np.zeros((N,M,3,3))
C[:,:,0,0] = a[:-1,:-1]
etc.
```

(or use `hstack` and `vstack` to the same effect).

But a nice thing (or maybe not so nice) about the strided approach is that it doesn't involve copy any data of `a` - it is just a view.

As to splitting the job into pieces, I can imagine using slices of `C` (on the 1st 2 dimensions), e.g.

```
 C[0:100,0:100,:,:].sum(axis=(2,3))
```